# merge dynamic multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry in advance if there is an answer for this, but I could not find exactly what I was looking for.

I currently have a reporting application that is returning data results into multi dimensional arrays from a database query.  Each array is build off of the id field. I would like to be able to merge arrays into one where the id is the same.

For example here is a test result set. As you can see the user with an id of 1 currently has two results.

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
    (
        [AssessmentQuestion] => 1
        [AssessmentAnswer] => 0
        [id] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [AssessmentQuestion] => 2
        [AssessmentAnswer] => 2
        [id] => 1
    )
)

Array
(   
    [0] => Array    
    (
        [AssessmentQuestion] => 1
        [AssessmentAnswer] => 1
        [id] => 2
    )
)
```

I would like the result set to look like this if the id's are the same.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [AssessmentQuestion] => 1
        [AssessmentAnswer] => 0
        [AssessmentQuestion] => 2
        [AssessmentAnswer] => 2
        [id] => 1
    )
)
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Here are the queries I'm running. There's a custom function ArrayFunctions::captureArrayFromResult(), this is just capturing the array results.
The first query just grabs all active user entry ids, and then per id returns all the
assessment question information.

```
/**** COLLECT ALL ACTIVE USER ENTRY IDS ****/
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT ue.id
          FROM user_entry ue
          LEFT JOIN user_demographic_answers uda ON ue.id = uda.user_entry_id
          LEFT JOIN user_assessment_answers uaa ON ue.id = uaa.user_entry_id 
          WHERE $condition
          AND DATE(ue.datetime_finished) BETWEEN '{$this->reportDateRangeStart}' AND    '{$this->reportDateRangeEnd}'";
$results = db_Query($query);
$this->reportUserEntryID = ArrayFunctions::captureArrayFromResult($results, "id", "id");

foreach($this->reportUserEntryID as $userID)
{
    /**** COLLECT ASSESSMENT QUESTIONS ****/
    $query = SELECT DISTINCT uaa.question_id as 'AssessmentQuestion', uaa.answer_value as 'AssessmentAnswer', ue.id
          FROM user_assessment_answers uaa
          LEFT JOIN report_field_options rfo ON uaa.question_id = rfo.assessment_question_id
          LEFT JOIN user_entry ue ON uaa.user_entry_id = ue.id
          WHERE ($condition)
          AND DATE(ue.datetime_finished) BETWEEN '{$this->reportDateRangeStart}' AND '{$this->reportDateRangeEnd}'
          AND ue.id IN ($userID)
          ORDER BY uaa.question_id";
    $results = db_Query($query);
    $this->reportQuestionAssessmentAnswers = ArrayFunctions::captureArrayFromResult($results);
}
```

Comment: There cannot be two different values with the same index.

Comment: Going off of fedorqui's comment; you could, however, change the value to an array of values. AssementQuestion => array(1,2)

Comment: Try using `$new_array_with_unique_id = array_unique($your_previous_array);`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: it's not possible to do what you're asking for, as array keys must be unique.

I would suggest, during your combining logic, to create an array of `AssesmentQuestions` and `AssesmentAnswers`, e.g.:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1,
        [AssesmentQuestions] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1,
            [1] => 2
        ),
        [AssesmentAnswers] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0,
            [1] => 2
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @jterry. I'm currently retrieving all of my data from one query, should I break that up into multiple queries per field then merge the information that way?

Comment: Yes. It would be better.

Comment: You can use my foreach loop to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach loop to achieve this :

```
$main_arr = array
(
     array
     (
         'AssessmentQuestion' => 1,
         'AssessmentAnswer' => 0,
         'id' => 1
     ),
     array
     (
         'AssessmentQuestion' => 2,
         'AssessmentAnswer' => 2,
         'id'=> 1
     ),
     array
     (
         'AssessmentQuestion' => 3,
         'AssessmentAnswer' => 4,
         'id' => 2
     ),
     array
     (
        'AssessmentQuestion' => 5,
        'AssessmentAnswer' => 6,
        'id'=> 1
     )
);

foreach ($main_arr as $arr) {
     $new_arr[$arr['id']]['id']  = $arr['id'];
     $new_arr[$arr['id']]['AssessmentQuestions'][] = $arr['AssessmentQuestion'];
     $new_arr[$arr['id']]['AssessmentAnswers'][] = $arr['AssessmentAnswer'];
}
var_dump($new_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks @Fouad Fodail. It seems that each following question is being build off of the previous.

Comment: I see this function should only be run if there are multiple arrays found with the same id.

Comment: Yes. according to your data samples.

Comment: The problem I'm having is my logic is nested inside a foreach loop, and I'm having difficulty determining whether the id is found multiple times or not.

Comment: I've added my query above.

Comment: Check the edited version who takes care of putting arrays with the same id together.

Comment: It looks to be adding the questions and answers from the first result onto the beginning of the second result.